# Resolving `Cannot execute sh: No such file or directory` after edit in adduser.conf

Tags: configuration

Recently i've edited `adduser.conf` which is located in /etc, and I've edited the `DSHELL` variable.

```
# The DSHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your
# system.
DSHELL=/bin/sh
```

While the original was

```
# The DSHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your
# system.
DSHELL=/bin/bash
```

The problem is after I've edited it and restarted the linux machine I'm getting the error `Cannot execute sh: No such file or directory` if I run `sudo su`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does `sudo -s` work?

Comment: Thanks It does work indeed, still what I'm thinking about is why it did work in the past and why now it doesn't work since that change. I got immediately root after that.

Comment: That's good; `sudo -s` is the modern alternative to `sudo su`. If you run `/bin/sh` do you get the same error as you described above, or do you get a shell?